# emacs and emacsclient colors

Tags: emacs

When I started to use emacs as daemon and emacsclient with new frame as interface, all was just fine. But then I wanted to adopt emacsclient for running in urxvt terminal. I’ve installed color-scheme package from my distro’s package manager and added initializing code to my ~/.emacs.d/init.el I switched between various color themes, but then realized that colors are actually depend of color palette of the terminal emacsclient is running in. So I deleted the color-theme package and removed lines related to it from my init.el. But something went wrong and I was left with default black foreground color, totally black cursor (I use only default X cursor which is black arrow outlined white, but what I got was looking almost like this, but totally black) and decreased font-size.

I was digging to fix all that as fast as possible, and started to use

```
 '(default-frame-alist (quote ((menu-bar-lines . 0) (left-fringe . 0) (right-fringe) (tool-bar-lines . 0) (background-color . "#2e3436") (foreground-color . "#d3d7cf") (cursor-color . "#ffffff"))))
```

This is what appeared in my custom-set-variables of my init.el after I finally hit on an appropriate item crawling the customize menu. However, now I need to specify more and more of things to make them look as in usual emacs (not as deamon, there colors and font are still fine). Then a question appeared: ‘Why before installation of color-theme frames of emacsclient were always inherit the default look of emacs I described through customize menu and saved to init.el?’

Answer (score 0):

Deleted all frame-related stuff from init.el and it works like before now.